# Why are THs bolder than TDs and how to avoid it?

Tags: css, fonts, html-table

***Edit June 14, 2015 - from this question, I learned that "bolder" and "lighter" are relative. The source that I referenced before said that "bolder" were an absolute measure and means "extra bold". I changed that source now :) (selfhtml.org wiki). Thanks all for your help.***

Please consider the following CSS:

```
table.a tr { font: bold 12pt Arial; }
table.b td,table.b th { font: bold 12pt Arial; }
```

and HTML (I compressed it a bit, it's also here: http://jsfiddle.net/b9uwnx31/

```
<body>
  <h2>Boldness Check</h2>
  <table class="a">
    <tr>
      <th>TH Column 1</th><td>TD Column 2</td><th>TH Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </table>  
  <table class="b">
    <tr>
      <th>TH Column 1</th><td>TD Column 2</td><th>TH Column 3</th>
    </tr>
  </table>  
</body>
```

Please look at the fiddle with Internet Explorer (10 or 11) and then with Chrome for Windows. Be careful that IE runs in standard mode.

I don't understand the different behavior of TH in Tables A and B. When I style the TR with font-weight:bold, the TH is rendered bolder. When I style the TH directly, TD and TH are rendered with the same weight.

This happens in Internet Explorer 9 and higher, it happens in Android Browser and Chrome for Android, but it does not happen in Chrome for Windows (those are the browsers I could check). Is this some kind of quirk? Or is it a feature that I don't know how to control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code snippet both in Firefox and Internet Explorer (latest versions) and indeed, there is a difference in how the boldness of the `th` elements is rendered by the two browsers.

The best explanation that I can offer is that the CSS specification does not say anything about how the font-weight of the `th` elements is to be computed, so how this is to be done is left up to the browser.

In both browsers, if you specify the font-weight on the `td` and `th` elements explicitly as in your Table B, then you get a consistent font-weight.  In Firefox, the value is set to `bold` and in Internet Explorer, the `bold` value is mapped to the font-weight scale value `700` for the Arial font.

In the case of Table A, the font-weight is applied to the parent element, the `tr` that contains the table cells.  In the case of Firefox, the CSS engine inherits the value from `tr`, that is `bold`, and you get the consistent font-weight.

However, for Internet Explorer, font weights are computed differently.  First, the IE CSS engine gets the inherited value, `bold`, and applies it to the `td` elements as a font-weight of `700`.  For the `th` element, the IE CSS engine appears to apply the equivalent of `bolder` instead of `bold`, and this leads to a computed font-weight of `900`, which makes the `th` elements look bolder.

What you are seeing here is a cross-browser difference due to how the software design engineers decided to interpret the CSS specification in a case where there were no explicit guidelines as to what to do.

I also noticed that if you change the font-family to something else, you may not see the problem, since browsers read font meta data to decide how to map the font-weight scale to the font-weights indicated in the font meta data.
(See http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/fonts.html#font-boldness for some indication of what the CSS engines may be doing in the background.)

As for a fix, well you more or less have it already.  Specify the font-weight explicitly by selecting `td` and `th` elements directly.

```css
table.a tr {
    font: bold 12pt Arial;
}
table.b td, table.b th {
    font: bold 12pt Arial;
}
```

```html
 <h2>Boldness Check</h2>

<table class="a">
    <tr>
        <th>TH Column 1</th>
        <td>TD Column 2</td>
        <th>TH Column 3</th>
    </tr>
</table>
<table class="b">
    <tr>
        <th>TH Column 1</th>
        <td>TD Column 2</td>
        <th>TH Column 3</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Well, I'll have to accept this. The browser is free to add some "non CSS behavior" to the rendering. In this case: "increase inherited font-weight by 20%". Probably this cannot be done by lesser CSS using mortals...

Comment: I have to eat my words - of course "th { font-weight:bolder }" is totally standard. But I misunderstood "bolder".

Comment: `bolder` is not a value I use very often, but it is very much part of the CSS spec.

Answer (score 1):

this looks perfectly normal to me. In table A, you don't say anything about how `<th>` or `<td>` should be styled, so default styling is used which means browsers can do *whatever* they want: styling a row does nothing to override column defaults.

With table B you explicitly say what should happen with the `<th>` and `<td>` styling, and so they look the same. In the latest IE:

[image]

Also note that, strictly speaking, `border-collapse` has nothing to do with this problem, as some answers are suggesting. It "solves" the problem by changing the styling semantics of the `<tr>` element. Instead, this really is purely a matter of "if you want to style elements the same, specify CSS for those elements, not just their parents"; if you have nested divs, you won't notice this being a problem, but if you have nested *different* elements, you may run into this, and your example is a perfect demonstrator of a practical case where this matters.

Comment: Good answer. By default the TH text is bold and centered align. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_th.asp

Comment: But my point is: I specified "bold" als font-weight for tr, and I expect that this weight is inherited by th and td. But it is not. th DOES inherit the tr font-weight, but modifies it. I also tried "normal" and "lighter". The rendering is often the same (but that's a browser Problem, they render only 2 or 3 different weights), but when I check the computed font-weight, I see that th increases the value by 100 or 200.

Comment: no, it doesn't. There is a CSS font-weight property `bolder` that makes sure an element is *always* bolder than its parent (unless that parent uses font-weight:900 of course), so instead of inheriting your `bold` rule, the table heading element has its own rule, and merely setting the value for `tr` does nothing to affect `th`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to style the `<TR>` tag.  In order to do that consistently across browsers, you need to set the table's `border-collapse` property to `collapse`.

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Now your rule for `<TR>` will apply.

Note, that `<TH>` tags are styled bold by default, which is why you were getting `<TH>` as bold, but `<TD>` as normal when you tried to style the `<TR>`.

Comment: No. My issue is that TD is styled as bold (font-weight 700), as expected, and TH changes its inherited value to 'bolder' (font-weight 900).